# Matching entire line of code (string format) with Python regex

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

Using Python and Regex, I have a string variable strSourceCode with the following

'\n    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);\r\n    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);\r\n    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);\r\n    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);\r\n    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);\r'

I would like to use re.findall and for example match the word 'allowance' and it should return back the entire line of code starting with \n and ending with \r, shown below

'\n    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);\r'

I've been struggling for couple of hours now and have decided to post. Any help would be great! Thank you.

I have tried re.M flag as well but it does not seem to work, I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com). Please put your code and variable contents in code blocks to improve readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will find any matches which start with '\n ', have anything before and after your keyword/key phrase, and end in '\r'.

```py
import re
strSourceCode = '\n function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);\r\n function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);\r\n function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);\r\n function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);\r\n function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);\r'

what_to_match = 'allowance'
pattern = f'\n .*{what_to_match}.*\r'
matches = re.findall(pattern, strSourceCode)
```